# Expectation of a conditioned geometric random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

So first let $X$ be the number of independent coin tosses until first head; $P(H)=p$. Suppose we have observed that the first coin toss is tails, what is the expectation $E[X-1|X>1]$?

So intuitively this is just equal to $E[X]$ which makes sense to me. I tried to derive this more formally:

$E[X-1|X>1]=\sum_xg(x)p_{X-1|X>1}(x)=\sum_x(x-1)p_{X-1|X>1}(x)$

Since a geometric random variable is memoryless, we have:

$E[X-1|X>1]=\sum_x(x-1)p_{x}(x)=E[X]-1$

I seem to be off by a factor of 1, I suspect it might be something to do with the fact that I am still summing over all $x$ as denoted in $\sum_x$ but I am not quite sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the issue here is in applying the law of the unconscious statistician with a mismatch in the random variable. Namely, conditioned on $X>1$ the random variable $Y := X-1$ has the same distribution as $X$. This means that $p_Y(k) = p_X(k)$ for all $k\geq 1$, indeed. So
$$
\mathbb{E}[X-1\mid X>1] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p_Y(k)
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p_X(k) = \mathbb{E}[X]\,.
$$
Howver, what you wrote is a bit different: what you wrote is
$$
\mathbb{E}[X-1\mid X>1] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)p_Y(k)
$$
which is different. The function $g$ you applied the LOTUS to seems OK, but then you ended up with $p_{X-1|X>1}$ (i.e., $p_{g(X)|X>1}$) instead of $p_{X|X>1}$ (this does not sound very formal as written, but that appears to be the crux of the issue).

Comment: Hmm, so in the lecture video I am studying, the professor states that $p_{X-1|X>1}(k)=p_{X}(k)$ (https://youtu.be/MuqLI4otMIQ?t=368), or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @jjl Mmh, let me check what I did and get back to you.

Comment: @jjl ou are right -- I used the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness#Discrete_memorylessness (for discrete memorylessness), and it looks like a $\geq $ there should be a $>$.

Comment: @jjl Updated my answer -- I have some trouble to make the exact issue formal, but my understanding is summarized in the last sentence.

Comment: Changing variables like you did makes sense with the derivation. The way I did it was I applied LOTUS according to $E[g(X)|A]=\sum_xg(x)p_{X|A}(x)$ from the lecture https://youtu.be/2_KBeHiUDiY?t=184. It's weird to me that this didn't work right off the bat. Maybe the formula is totally universal for cases like this?

Comment: Well, here you don't have $p_{X|A}$, you have $p_{X-1|A}$, these are not the same. @jjl

Comment: Oh, you're right, I should have had $p_{X|A}$. But then I still end up with $\sum_x(x-1)p_{X|X>1}(x)$ at the end? And from the memorylessness property I believe $p_{X|X>1}(x)=p_{X}(x)$ so I run into the same problem?

Comment: No, that last part is no longer true. The memorylessness property does not give you that (as an example, $p_{X|X>1}(1)\neq p_X(1)$). See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness#A_frequent_misunderstanding